# no matching function for call to 'fromMsg(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> >::_transform_type, tf2::Transform&)'

Tags: navigation, catkin, compilation, cross-compiling, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently trying to cross compile the [robot-localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package for a custom made OS with yocto. I managed to cross compile the other dependencies but I got a problem with this one.

I did 2 modifications in the CMakelists.txt from origin, you can see mine here http://pastebin.com/XYy53Cfs.

During compilation, it stops at 70%. I think there is a problem with the tf2-geometry-msgs library. It is included but the issue is in the fromMsg method.

```
[ 70%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ros_filter_utilities.dir/src/ros_filter_utilities.cpp.o

/home/david/Documents/NEOCORTEX-OS/build/tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/robot-localization/2.2.1-r0/robot_localization-2.2.1/src/ros_filter_utilities.cpp: In function 'bool RobotLocalization::RosFilterUtilities::lookupTransformSafe(const tf2_ros::Buffer&, const string&, const string&, const ros::Time&, tf2::Transform&)':

/home/david/Documents/NEOCORTEX-OS/build/tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/robot-localization/2.2.1-r0/robot_localization-2.2.1/src/ros_filter_utilities.cpp:80:104: error: no matching function for call to 'fromMsg(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> >::_transform_type, tf2::Transform&)'
     tf2::fromMsg(buffer.lookupTransform(targetFrame, sourceFrame, time).transform, targetFrameTrans);
                                                                                                    ^
/home/david/Documents/NEOCORTEX-OS/build/tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/robot-localization/2.2.1-r0/robot_localization-2.2.1/src/ros_filter_utilities.cpp:80:104: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/david/Documents/NEOCORTEX-OS/build/tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/robot-localization/2.2.1-r0/robot_localization-2.2.1/src/ros_filter_utilities.cpp:36:0:
```

[...]

```
make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

In the cpp file

```
try
{
 tf2::fromMsg(buffer.lookupTransform(targetFrame, sourceFrame, time).transform, targetFrameTrans);
}
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211517/no-matching-function-for-call-to-%27frommsg(geometry_msgs::transformstamped_%3Cstd::allocator%3Cvoid%3E-%3E::_transform_type,-tf2::transform&)%27-tf2::frommsg(buffer.lookuptransform(targetframe,-sourceframe,-time).transform,-targetframetrans);/) by [Dben](https://answers.ros.org/users/22364/dben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you certain you're using the latest release of the `tf2_geometry_msgs` package (0.5.11)? The method that it's looking for is [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/0.5.11/tf2_geometry_msgs/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h#L298-L304). If you're building from source, look at the file `tf2_geometry_msgs/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h` and make sure you see that method.

EDIT: Also, you shouldn't need to modify the CMakeLists.txt file. I've compiled `robot_localization` on an ARM board (an ODROID U3) and it builds fine.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1